# Mapping state In React-Leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, mapping, react-leaflet

I am stuck trying to map state in my React-Leaflet project.
  Here is my state and what I do to get a marker on my map.

```
this.state = {
   markers: [
       {
          _id: 'SomeId',
          position:[51.509,-0.03],
          content: 'Something'}
       }
   ]      
}


{this.state.markers.map((position, _id, content) => 
       <Marker 
           key={_id} 
           position={position}>
       <Popup>
         <span>{content}</span>       
       </Popup>
     </Marker>
)}
```

I get

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the error is generated by other part of your code because in what you included there is not a lat property of any object.

So in order to render a marker from an array of objects stored in state you should destructure the object properties inside markers array while looping with map in order to use them directly:

```
{this.state.markers.map(({position, _id, content}) => 
       <Marker
            key={_id}
            position={position}
            icon={customMarker}>
            <Popup>
              {content}
            </Popup>
       </Marker>)
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mapping-state-in-react-leaflet-cwsmp)

Answer (score 0):

The callback-function takes 3 arguments and the first argument is the current entry within the array. The necessary properties have to be accessed through it.

```
{this.state.markers.map(marker =>
  <Marker key={marker._id} position={marker.position}>
    <Popup>
      <span> <br/> {marker.content}</span> 
    </Popup>  
  </Marker> 
)}
```